# Is it possible to screw up the Crystarium?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

This is really revamped from the way it worked in the first game, so here's a few related inquiries about how this thing actually works.

- Is the Crystarium infinite?  Once I learn all the abilities, can I just keep increasing my stats forever?
- If it's not infinite, is it possible to max out all 6 roles?  Possible to get all the Crystarium level bonuses?
- Are the max stats achievable fixed, or do I very carefully need to balance which sized nodes I give to which job in order to not screw up my stats for endgame?

Basically, "Do I need to very carefully plan my level ups in advance, or can I just spend my CP immediately without thinking about it?"  I don't want to accidentally cripple my stats.

Comment: I'd point out that I've only played the demo so far, so if this is spelled out in the full game I apologize.  (I very seriously doubted they'd spell this out, though.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible to max out every role to level 99. Once you have done so you can't level up the Crystarium any further. And just FYI the last 100 or so levels of the Crystarium are exponentially more expensive. Something in the neighborhood of 2k per orb.

Your max stats are **not** fixed, so in a sense, *you can screw up the Crystarium*. If you'll notice, when you are on a large orb that isn't a skill you'll get an additional bonus depending on what role you level at that point. So let's say you're leveling Noel and you take a `COM` level at a large orb. You'll get a bonus to that particular role. So although every role can hit 99 if you want Noel to be a strong `COM` you would want to always level `COM` on a large orb. In effect **the number of large orbs is fixed**.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting, but makes sense as it forces you to play with and level up the monsters to plug your team holes.

Comment: @DavidYell The advantages for *"doing it right"* are minor anyway. But a perfectionist would want to unlock all the roles as soon as possible simply to use the weaker ones (or less often used) as a place to dump sacrificial points.

Comment: I mastered a role last night (lv99) and then moved onto a new role, which still had 'large orbs' to unlock. So it's possible to level RAV for MAG and then COM for STR after each other, but as mentioned it will cost lots. My secondary role's start at 420cp per orb.

Comment: My only concern is if you leave the role unlocks until later on, you'll have to expend huge amounts of CP to level the crystarium of a role you don't like to allow you to unlock the new role.

Comment: As the guy who spent 200+ hours on the Sphere Grid deleting all the +1/+2/+3 stat orbs and replacing them with +4 orbs, I am the perfectionist in question.  It's good to know there's not much advantage for "doing it right", though (which is UNLIKE FFX).

Answer (score 3):

I found this guide today and think it might be helpful to anyone coming back to this question. http://uk.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-xiii-2/Recommended_Crystarium_Growth

It also backs up what Yuck was saying about distributing the points amongst the larger spheres.